# WinJS: Best Way To Save Important Information

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a Windows Store app that I've created for my business. My business has been using it for months successfully, but we get occasional errors with reading saved data; it's very, very important that I figure out a way to minimize these data-saving and reading errors.

Let me be specific: my app is essentially a Timesheet app: an employee can sign in and out of work with my app. I save each shift to an Azure database, but because of unreliable internet, I save the shift objects to a file in the localdata, in JSON.stringify format. I use this function to write the information (and I write to file pretty any time a shift is started or finished):

```
            jsonWrite: function (fileName, object) {
                return localFolder.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists)
                    .then(function (file) {
                        return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, JSON.stringify(object));
                    })
            }
```

I use this function to read the information for loading when the app starts up again:

```
            jsonRead: function (fileName) {
                return localFolder.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists)
                    .then(function (file) {
                        return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file)
                    })
                    .then(function(text) {
                        return text ? JSON.parse(text) : null;
                    })
            },
```

Only very occasionally do I get an error writing to file. I find out about the error later, when the app starts up again and one of the files is in a non-JSON.parsable format.

Now, the most obvious solution -- but the incorrect one -- is to have some sort of error handler for an incorrect file read that initializes the data for a file it can't read. But I can't do that, because if a file is unreadable, that means potentially shifts that employees have worked have been lost -- I can't just silently fail there; I need to know that that data has been lost because it's obviously very important, so so far I've allowed the app to just crash in the rare cases that that happens (it's happened maybe 3 times in 5 months).

I've read about other data storage solutions, other than just writing text to a file -- IndexDB, storage containers, etc.

Given that I could have up to 32Kb of data to save, what's the most appropriate option? And how do I avoid data loss?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely an odd solution to have. IndexedDB may be your best bet here. Not sure of how to avoid the data loss without a Try/Catch for the exception.

Is there a way to store the data locally until you can compare it with the online DB, do a comparison, then use whichever you determine is best?

Is it possible to throw a warning to the end user that the file was not properly saved, thereby requesting that they enter the info again?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No way to really throw a warning that the file was not properly saved for them to re-enter info, because they didn't really 'enter' the info in the first place -- the info is maybe the last day or last 2 days of employees' shifts. But I'm thinking IndexDB might be my best bet